# How can I make generate_series work for part of a month?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, generate-series, set-returning-functions

I'm using filled_months to fill blank months in and group data by months. The problem is I can't seem to make it work for querying partial months (e.g. 2016-09-01 to 2016-09-15), it always counts the full month. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
with filled_months AS
  (SELECT
   month,
          0 AS blank_count
   FROM generate_series(date_trunc('month',date('2016-09-01')), date_trunc('month',date('2016-09-15')), '1 month') AS
   month)
SELECT to_char(mnth.month, 'YYYY Mon') AS month_year,
       count(distinct places.id)
FROM filled_months mnth
left outer join restaurants
  ON date_trunc('month', restaurants.created_at) = mnth.month
left outer join places
  ON restaurants.places_id = places.id
WHERE places.id IS NULL OR restaurants.id IS NULL
GROUP BY mnth.month
ORDER BY mnth.month
```

Comment: The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your quandary correctly, I don't think you even need the generate series here.  I think you can get by with a `between` in your where clause and let the grouping in SQL handle the rest:

```
SELECT
  to_char(r.created_at, 'YYYY Mon') AS month,
  count(distinct p.id)
FROM
  restaurants r
  left join places p ON r.places_id = p.id
WHERE
  r.created_at between '2016-09-01' and '2016-09-15'
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

I tested this on three records with dates, 9/1/16, 9/15/16 and 9/30/16, and it gave a count of two.  When I expanded the range to 9/30 it correctly gave three.

DISCLAIMER:  I didn't understand what this meant:

```
places.id IS NULL OR restaurants.id IS NULL
```

If this doesn't work, then perhaps you can add some sample data to your question, along with some expected results.